# Will this inner tube work for my bike?

Tags: innertube

Some context, I am currently at home from university and I am looking to buy a new inner tube for my bike that I have at uni. As I am no expert I decided to consult here whether the tube I have found here would work. (All details below are deduced from pixelated images and memory, so please let me know if I have listed details about my rim & tyre that would be incompatible)

So essentially, I think my rims are ETRTO 622x17c. And my tyre's are 700cx35c. I know that the valve I had in my burst inner tube is a Dunlop valve and ideally I would like to keep it the same.

So the inner tube that I have found has the following parameters:
**700 x 35-43C (35/44-622/630) DV 40mm for a 700 (28inch) wheel.**

[Link to product](https://www.yesshop.cz/duse-kls-700-x-35-43c--35-44-622-630--dv-40mm/)

Thank you very much in advance for any responses!

Comment: are you positive its a Dunlop valve (aka a Woods valve)  ?   Presta uses the same pump and rim hole.

Comment: Presta does not use the same rim hole. Presta has a smaller hole than Dunlop and Schrader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will work. Inner tubes fit a broad range of tires.

FWIW, Dunlop valves are uncommon (I don't think I've ever seen one on a bike). But if that's what you've got on the other wheel, I can understand wanting to keep them the same.

Comment: Yeah I have read that they are uncommon globally, but where I study that being the Netherlands they are more widely used. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yeah – in the Netherlands and Germany, Dunlop is kind of the default. Presta valves are called “Französische Ventile” and Schrader “Autoventile” in Germany. Personally I don't think it really matters what valves you use – most pumps nowadays work with both Presta and Schrader, and the former fits Dunlop as well. Presta are a bit more responsive than the other types for quickly changing pressure, if you know what you're doing, and a bit more fiddly if you don't.

Comment: I learned something new today.